# How to remove all polylines I've created at once?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I made a React Page and I have an array of objects. Every object has an array of coordinates.

So for every object I created a Polyline

```
  if(travel.waypoints.length > 0 ) {
            let t = travel.waypoints;
           t.forEach((w) => {
              // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
             let poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: w.coords,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: w.car ? '#160BB9' : w.foothorse ? '#13A155' : w.train ? '#931083' : w.ship ? '#E0DB34' : w.plane ? '#B23511' : '#000' ,
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight:6, 
                editable: false,
                draggable: false,
                clickable: true,
                
             })
             poly.addListener('click', (event) => {
                navigate(`/add-travel/editwaypoint?draft=${params}?wid=${w.id}`)
             })
             poly.setMap(map)
           })
        }
```

But what I am trying to do is to remove all polylines at once.

I tried using a map.clear(), but my map object doesn't have that attribute.

I have my map declared like this:

```
import { useJsApiLoader, GoogleMap, Marker, Autocomplete, DirectionsRenderer } from '@react-google-maps/api'

 // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const [map, setMap] = useState(/** @type google.maps.Map */(null))

   <GoogleMap
      center={center}
      zoom={3}
      onLoad={(map) => setMap(map)}
      mapContainerStyle={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}

      >
                              
   </GoogleMap>
```

UPDATE.
I also tried to store every poly in an array. And then when I want to clear them to use array.forEach((t) => t.path = []), but it didn't work, the error said something like to many re-renders when I stored them.

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox or a snippet that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Empty an array / object using State Hooks

What you could use here is to use `React.useState` to store your array of coordinates for your polyline. than use the `setState` method to replace it with an empty one.

It should look something like this:

```
  // custom path array of lat lng objects, 
  // this could be made by iterating through Directions results
  const [path, setPath] = React.useState([
    { lat: 41.8781139, lng: -87.6297872 },
    { lat: 41.8781139, lng: -87.6297872 },
    { lat: 41.8769003, lng: -87.6297353 },
    { lat: 41.8768866, lng: -87.63073 },
    { lat: 41.8689131, lng: -87.630596 },
    { lat: 41.852949, lng: -87.6300619 },
    { lat: 41.85294, lng: -87.6310536 },
    { lat: 41.8500987, lng: -87.6310927 }
  ]);

  // empty loadPolyline that we're gonna fill with the path.
  const [loadPolyline, setLoadPolyline] = React.useState([]);
```

For example, if you want your polyline to show when the map loads, it should look like this:

```
const onMapLoad = React.useEffect(() => {
    // When the map loads, the value of `loadPolyline` gets filled by the path array
    setLoadPolyline(path);
  }, [path]);
```

Then to remove it, you just have to use `setLoadPolyline()` and `setPath()` by resetting the values inside `path` and `loadPolyline`. It should look something like this:

```
const clearPolyline = () => {
    console.log("polyline cleared!");
    // reset the values inside `path` and `loadPolyline`
    setPath([]);
    setLoadPolyline([]);
};
```

With this, the polyline should be removed.

Here's a proof of concept snippet for you to check: https://codesandbox.io/s/proof-of-concept-for-removing-polylines-no1pup

Hope this helps!